# Embed a music player on email

Tags: html, flash, templates, email

I'm creating html to send by email, and i want to put a music player like SoundCloud, I recieve an email who include that.

```
<object height="81" width="100%">
    <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F1627309%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-B1hMj&secret_url=false">
    </param> 
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    </param> 
    <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F1627309%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-B1hMj&secret_url=false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed>
</object>
```

This is the code of the player.

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 4):

Most email clients will reject your object/embed tags.

**Flash & Javascript [are not allowed](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1974/the-truth-about-1/) in Email Newsletters.**

**Update** - Apparently this actually is possible in Apple Mail, all others will fail though.

See http://support.soundcloud.com/soundcloud/topics/embedding_soundcloud_mix_on_email_ive_seen_it_done_but_dont_know_how?from_gsfn=true

Comment: yes i know that, but i've already recieve and email with an soundcloud player embed, and i can't saw the source that they used to embed that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the support is similar to video as the only technique for both is with HTML5. You'll have to be mindful of the fallbacks however, as it is not 100% supported.

[This link](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/a_how_to_guide_to_embedding_html5_video_in_email) has info on how to embed (video) and also the support chart.

Here is [another link](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2905/html5-and-video-in-email/).